# Java array - Adjacent cards

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that arranges 6 cards on a grid in a specific way so that no card is adjacent to other cards of the same type (the types being king, queen and jack). The grid is 4x4 but I can only place cards inside the following pattern:

```
[ ][ ][x][ ]
[x][x][x][ ]
[ ][x][x][x]
[ ][ ][x][ ]
```

Now, my main problem is when my method tries to check the adjacent cells for card types. When it starts at 0,0 it tries to check [row-1][column] which obviously won't work since that translates to -1,0. The problem is, I have no idea how implement this properly.

I apologise if this question has been asked before, as I wasn't sure what to search for exactly (or how to properly name this problem).

```
private boolean bordersCard(int row, int column, char cardChar)
    {
        Candidate center = board[row][column];
        Candidate top;
        Candidate bottom;
        Candidate left;
        Candidate right;

        if (board[row-1][column] != null){
            top = board[row+1][column];
        }
        else
        {
            top = new Candidate('?', 0);
        }

        if (board[row+1][column] != null){
            bottom = board[row+1][column];
        }
        else
        {
            bottom = new Candidate('?', 0);
        }

        if (board[row][column-1] != null){
            left = board[row][column-1];
        }
        else
        {
            left = new Candidate('?', 0);
        }
        if (board[row][column+1] != null){
            right = board[row][column+1];
        }
        else
        {
            right = new Candidate('?', 0);
        }

        if ((center.getCardChar() == top.getCardChar()) || (center.getCardChar() == bottom.getCardChar()) ||
        (center.getCardChar() == left.getCardChar()) || (center.getCardChar() == right.getCardChar())){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `if` fences to prevent the invalid checks:

```
if (row > 0 && board[row-1][column] != null){
    top = board[row+1][column];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have determined, checking [-1][0] doesn't work.  But you don't need to check that non-existent slot.  Just make sure you don't run off the beginning or the end of the array.  Also, make sure you are performing the same math operation inside your `if` as in your condition:

```
if ((row - 1) >= 0 && (row - 1) < board.length && board[row-1][column] != null){
     top = board[row-1][column];  // Use -1 to match condition.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the indexes are out of bounds assign them to NULL. In Candidate create a method isSameType(Candidate other);

```
isSameType(Candidate other)
{
   if(other == null)
    return false;
   else
    retrun getCardChar() == other.getCardChar();
}
```

change your if to:

```
if(center.isSameType(top) || center.isSameType(bottom) || ...)
{
   return false;
}
```